# Query startAt and endAt for a date in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data structure:

```
attendance
--- 2020-02-09-PM
--- 2020-02-11-PM
--- 2020-02-16-AM
--- 2020-02-16-PM
--- 2020-02-18-PM
```

I wanted to get for example the date of 2020-02-16, I would need both PM and AM.  So I wanted to query my DB to only get that data.

Here is my attempt:

```
function getAttendanceCount(orgUid, dates) {
   orgUid.forEach(uid => {
     dates.forEach(date => {
       const getAttendCount = fDB.ref(`organization/${uid}/attendance`)
      .orderByChild('attendance')
      .startAt(date+'-AM')
      .endAt(date+'-PM')
      .once('value')
      .then(c => console.log(c.val()));
   });
 })
}
```

My console.log is null.
Any idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
const getAttendCount = fDB.ref(`organization/${uid}/attendance`)
      .orderByChild('attendance')
```

Into this:

```
const getAttendCount = fDB.ref(`organization/${uid}/attendance`)
      .orderByKey()
```

The reason you need to use `orderByKey()` is because the date are acting as a key and not as a `child` which would have a value example:

```
"name" : "peter"
```